# NSManagedObject key exists in the entity description but when trying to access it the app crashes with "this class is not key value coding-compliant"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a NSManangedObject that displays all the correct attributes in the entity description. But whenever I try to access one of the attributes it crashes saying it is not key-value coding compliant.

I have triple checked my datamodel and the entity class and everything looks correct.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I am accessing the object from a notification. Here is an example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = notification.userInfo;
NSSet *set = [dict objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

for (NSManagedObject* managedObject in set) {
    NSLog(@"%@", managedObject.entity.attributesByName);
    if([managedObject.entity.attributesByName valueForKey:@"defaultid"] != nil) {
        NSLog(@"defaultid: %@", [managedObject valueForKey:@"defaultid"]);
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
{
    defaultid = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x175c90>), name defaultid, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity MyEntity, renamingIdentifier defaultid, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
    title = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x175ce0>), name title, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity MyEntity, renamingIdentifier title, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
}
```

And then crash with the following:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_NSObjectID_64_6 0x6119020> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key defaultid.'
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The notification is from iCloud which calls this method:

```
- (void)mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    [moc performBlock:^{
        [self mergeiCloudChanges:notification forContext:moc];
    }];
}
```

The above code is in the mergeiCloudChanges method.

EDIT 2 (SOLVED):

So it turns out I made a stupid mistake. I thought [dict objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey] returned a set of managedObjects but what it does is return a set a managedObjectIDs.

This works:

```
NSDictionary *dict = note.userInfo;
NSSet *set = [dict objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
for (NSManagedObjectID* managedObjectID in set) {
    NSManagedObject *newObject = [moc existingObjectWithID:managedObjectID error:nil];
}
```

Thanks to everyone for their time.

Comment: What is the line of code that causes the crash?

Comment: It's this bit that causes the actual crash: [managedObject valueForKey:@"defaultid"]

Comment: Your code seems fine to me and runs without any exceptions on my setup. Which notification are you subscribing? Is there any threading involved?

Comment: It is an icloud coredata sync notification. There is some threading. I will add the code to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed since you asked this question, but I'm seeing the actual NSManagedObject instances in the NSSet for `NSInsertedObjectsKey`. In my case, it was for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification. Figured I'd post this in case anyone sees this SO post and assumes they're NSManagedObjectID objects (as I did :-P).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell in the entity description, you have defaultid marked as optional. Does it exist for the entity you are accessing? If you turn off optional and give it a default value, what would happen?

Comment: Thanks but the optional shouldn't make it crash. If there is no value for defaultid the object will return nil. Almost every field in my app is optional, but everywhere else nil still gets returned.